# Google app "Keep": only show unchecked (unarchived) list items when exporting?

Tags: google-keep

I use Keep for maintaining a reusable shopping list. (Shared with family on other devices). I mark the item with a checkbox when bought for later use.

But if I want to send the list (eg via email) surprisingly it exports all items in the list, both checked (archived) and unchecked! So when I export it, I have to manually delete each of the checked rows from the email before sending. Is there a way around this?